# Best way to test UI after the application is ready

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have an angular 5 application which has multiple components out of which several are interrelated and also have material dependencies.What's the best way to test my application's UI?I tried using Jasmine/Karma but it does not look at all elegant as it's supposed to be used in TDD scenarios and my code is already developed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop some Behaviour Tests with Karma and Selenium/Fluentlenium with Angular 5. That way you will be able to test the components but also the communication and global operations of your application.

Note that you will need a specific database and depending on the size of your application they can take some time to excecute.

Comment: Hi
Can you provide a link that might help me in doing this?

Comment: I don't know if you are confortable with java but you have to create a new java module to run your bdd tests. You need to run your application and then provide your application's url to your dbb module. If this could be a solution for you you can look at this link http://fluentlenium.org/